# How to make SLDS grid columns fill 100% of available height on the screen?

Tags: slds, slds-grid

I would like to create a layout similar to this:

[image]

I have this code:

```
    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-grid_vertical-stretch">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">
            <article class="slds-card">
                Left side
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_9-of-12">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-stretch">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <article class="slds-card">
                        <span>top left</span>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <article class="slds-card">
                        <span>top right</span>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <article class="slds-card">
                        <span>bottom left</span>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <article class="slds-card">
                        <span>bottom right</span>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am using `slds-grid_vertical-stretch` but this only seems to work when there is a parent element with a fixed height, rather than a variable/flexiable height.

I cannot figure out how to make the fill 100% of the available height on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what I needed I had to use a CSS property called `calc()` this article was useful: [A Couple of Use Cases for Calc()](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)

> calc() is a native CSS way to do simple math right in CSS as a
> replacement for any length value (or pretty much any number value). It
> has four simple math operators: add (+), subtract (-), multiply (*),
> and divide (/). Being able to do math in code is nice and a welcome
> addition to a language that is fairly number heavy.

The `html` template has two custom css classes: `c-container` and `full-height`

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-stretch c-container">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">
        <article class="slds-card">
            Left side
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_9-of-12">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-stretch full-height">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <article class="slds-card">
                    <span>top left</span>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <article class="slds-card">
                    <span>top right</span>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <article class="slds-card">
                    <span>bottom left</span>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <article class="slds-card">
                    <span>bottom right</span>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
.c-container {    
    margin: 0;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 250px); <--- The key ingredient 
}

article.slds-card {
    height: 100%;
}

.full-height {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Notice the use of `calc()`:

```
min-height: calc(100vh - 250px);
```

Answer (score 2):

Now, this is even easier using the `lightning-layout`. Set `vertical-align="stretch"` for the `lightning-layout`. For the enclosed elements set `height:100%`. That's it. No more need for `calc()`.